# How to add new element inside react-markdown content in nextjs without using jsx?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, css-selectors, react-markdown, typewriter

I use react-markdown to build the virtual dom which allows for updating only the changing DOM instead of completely overwriting. It generate the content in

tag. I want to add  tag inside

tag.

```
                <ReactMarkdown
              components={
                {
                code({ node, inline, className, children, ...props }) {
                  const match = /language-(\w+)/.exec(className || '');
                  return !inline && match ? (
                    <SyntaxHighlighter
                      {...props}
                      style={a11yDark}
                      language={match[1]}
                      PreTag="div"
                    >
                      {String(children).replace(/\n$/, '')}
                    </SyntaxHighlighter>
                  ) : (
                    <code {...props} className={className}>
                      {children}
                    </code>
                  );
                },
              }}
            >
              {content}
            </ReactMarkdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be using a custom render function for the paragraph node type.I don't exact thing but may be this will help.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';

const renderers = {
  paragraph: ({ node, ...props }) => {
    return <p {...props}><span>Your additional content here</span>{node.children}</p>;
  },
  // Use your custom renderers as needed
};

const content = 'Your markdown content here';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ReactMarkdown renderers={renderers}>
      {content}
    </ReactMarkdown>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: No, i dont want to add a tag inside the code tag.  ReactMarkdown will generate content in a <p> tag and my archive is add a <span> tag inside this <p> tag

Comment: Okay. To to add a <span> tag inside the <p> tag you can use a custom render function for the paragraph node type.